# Lambda expression to select object and its collection where collection contains only active items

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to select the object including its collection, this collection must contain only ative items.

**This is the call:**

```
EntityResult<TEntity> = SelecFor( LAMBDA_EXPRESSION , "NameOfCollectionPropertyToInclude");
```

I know I can query it in repository layer level, but I would like to perform it here if it's possible

**This is the method:**

```
public virtual EntityResult<TEntity> SelectFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>, params string[] entitiesToLoad)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, you cast your entity to [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx), you include the entities then filter.

```
public async Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsyncEager(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }
        return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
    }
```

The second expression allow you to pass a lambda. Es:

```
repository.SingleOrdDefaultAsyncEager(x=> x.Id == 5, y=> y.collection);
```